# How to include a class file in drupal 6 while bootstrap

Tags: php, drupal

I want to include a set of class files while bootstrap in drupal 6. Can anyone suggest how to achieve this in drupal way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include a file during bootstrap, you can use [hook_boot](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_boot/6). You may also be able to use [hook_init](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_init/6) you should make sure you understand how that hook is called when pages are cached.

A word of warning - including PHP during bootstrap impacts performance and is often unnecessary. There's usually a smarter way of including what you need, optimally it's only loaded when it's needed.